# Why session becomes empty hash in integration rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Here is our integration test case which is under spec/features/. The purpose of the rspec is to login first and then open up the user menus page and test the link on the use menu page. It is a rails 3.2.12 app. Here is the rspec code:

```
describe "CheckLinks" do
  describe "GET /check_links" do
    before(:each) do

      ...data...

      visit '/'
      save_and_open_page      
      fill_in "login", :with => @u.login
      fill_in "password", :with => 'password'
      click_button 'Login'
      #save_and_open_page
    end
      
    it "works" do
      visit user_menus_path 
      save_and_open_page     
      click_link('Project')
      save_and_open_page
      page.body.should have_content('Project#') #('Project Number')
    end
  end
end
```

The rspec error is simple:

```
  1) CheckLinks GET /check_links works
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mpage.body.should have_content('Project#') #('Project Number')←[0m
       ←[31mexpected to find text "Project#" in "Login Page"←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/features/check_links_spec.rb:116:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

What we found out was that the session was `empty hash` after `click_link('project')` and it causes the app to `redirect_to signin` page. However in code execution, the `Project` link page did bring us to the index page for the project. Why the session becomes `empty hash` in rspec after `click_link`. Is there problem with our rspec code?

Comment: what version number are you using on both rspec-rails and capybara?

Comment: rspec-rails: 2.13.1, capybora: 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things, first I don't believe you need `body` in your test. Just do

```
page.should have_content('Project#')
```

Also, make sure whatever `('Project#')` is evaluated to is correct. It tries to match it literally. This could be wrong and thats your failure.

The big thing is that the Capybara DSL, the `page` and `visit` method has been moved to feature specs. It is not available in request and controller specs. Take a look at the [upgrading to capybara 2](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md) section of the docs. This may be your problem. You can work around this and include the Capybara DSL in the integration test by including this in your `spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Capybara::DSL, :example_group => {
  :file_path => "spec/requests"
  }
end
```

But you should really do this kind of test in a feature spec and follow the new convention.

Comment: The integration test in the post is indeed under spec/features/ (was moved from spec/requests/ which is the default by rails g integration_test). There is nothing under spec/requests